# American English Slang Phrase for "see you in court"?

Tags: slang, offensive-language, metaphors

I'm trying to recall a phrase it goes along the lines of "choose ___" where ___ is a number. OR "pick ___" (I can't remember which word exactly).

The explanation of the phrase is that in either civil or criminal court there are a ___ number of jurors so the idea is that by saying this phrase you are basically saying "i'll see you in court" as in "find ___ jurors".

I tried googling "choose 9", "choose 12", "pick 6" (wrong phrase its used in football), and now I have garbled my memory so I don't know which word + number to use. It might also not be "pick/choose" but be "find" or some other similar verb.

This phrase has been featured in some hip hop songs but I can't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: Do you think it is a set phrase or just a one off usage in the lyrics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The song is "I Shot Ya (Remix)" by LL Cool J featuring Keith Murray, Prodigy, Fat Joe, and Foxy Brown.

> I be the one to represent the streets
> If you ever test my heat, then I'ma test my heat
> You violate, I'ma get you, I'ma hit you
> And if you lucky, I might just send you to your crew
> Cause if I go to jail, kid, you know the routine
> Pick 12 jurors, hope the judge ain't mean

*Pick 12 jurors* here may mean *see you in court*, but it seems open to some interpretation. It's not a common phrase: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pick%2012%20jurors%2Cselect%2012%20jurors&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows no examples, whereas *select 12 jurors* registers somewhere above zero since 1910 or so.

Comment: I am like 100% sure now its "pick 12". I heard this phrase being used casually by some acquaintances who explained its meaning to me.

Comment: The number 12 being associated with juries is fairly well-known though. For example, there's a famous play/movie about a jury deliberation named [12 Angry Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Angry_Men_(1957_film))

Comment: Neither party in a court case actually picks the jurors, so it doesn't make a lot of sense. Although rap no more has to make sense than a Cole Porter lyric does.

Comment: @StuartF It's called poetic license. And it's not really that far off, both parties participate in the process of selecting the jurors. And it's not even clear who is doing the picking in those jurors, it might be short for "12 jurors will be picked".

Comment: It actually makes sense because theres an implied offense here. When I hear "pick 12" I'm also basically hearing: "why don't you go ahead and find some jurors this isn't worth my time I got more important things to do [unlike you]", or "go ahead rig the jury it won't make a difference/i don't fear you", "